# How to connect to socket with Socket.io-client in Vue-cli app

Tags: sockets, vue.js, socket.io, vuex

So, I'm buidling an app, and I have to use a socket URL, and socket.io to connect to it.
I'm wondering what is the best way to connect from the client side in a Vue-CLI app. When i insert it to created, the app becomes incredibly slow.

```
var configUrl = "CONFIG_URL";
// Axios request to retrieve socket URL
axios.get(configUrl).then((response) => {
  var socketUrl = response.data.config.liveDistributionSSL;
  var socket = io(socketUrl);

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected");
    socket.emit("subscribe", {
      subscribeMode: "topSportBets",
      language: {
        default: "en"
      },
      deliveryPlatform: "WebSubscribe",
      playerUuid: null,
      subscribeOptions: {
        autoSubscribe: true,
        betCount: 3,
        excludeMeta: false,
        resubscriptions: 0,
        fullBetMeta: true,
        browser: {}
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("message", (message) => {
    switch (message.type) {
      case "state":
        //Calling commit on an mutation to add data to it sent from socket
        commit('updateData', message.data);
        console.log("Data =>", message.data)
        break;
      case "currentMatches":
        // We have matches to update
        break;
      case "betchange":
        // We have match bets to update
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

I'm using Vuex, and I've put this code in an action which I call from Created lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you should not set the socket connection in the action. Only the requests to/from Socketio.

You don't need to make the connection everytime the action is called, Socketio will handle the connection until it's closed or the client gets disconnected.
Just make the connection one time with calling the mutation `SOCKET_CONNECT` (using `commit`), for example from your main Vue file.

See the example below : https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not using Vue-socket, just Socket.io. Those are the terms for the task. I'm not really experienced with Socket.io.